# How do I implement ‘sign in with google’ on my site?

Tags: authentication, gmail, google-oauth, cross-domain, openid

On my site I would like to allow users to sign in with a google account. I plan to use openid but I would like to allow signing in with google because it has more benefits. I've noticed in the past a few sites that have the ability to sign in with a google (gmail) account and IIRC  though they did NOT support openID (but I could be wrong).

How do I implement 'sign in with google'?

Comment: You can use E-GOOGLE-OAUTH-BUTTON from EHTML:  https://github.com/Guseyn/EHTML

Answer (score 32):

If you plan to use OpenID, use that.  Google is already an OpenID 2.0 provider.

Google's OpenID provider is located at: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud

(NOTE: There's no point visiting that URI in your browser, but it does work for OpenID.)

<strike>This is primarily addressed on the [Accounts API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/) page, which also addresses OAuth and the hybrid and proprietary login systems.  Depending on your site, you may also want to use [Friend Connect](http://code.google.com/apis/friendconnect/), which is an OpenSocial container that internally uses OpenID for authentication.</strike>

I'm of course biased towards Friend Connect, since I'm the DPE for that project, but you're probably better served directly using the OpenID provider unless you're also doing stuff that involves a social graph.

**Edit for 2012:** You want to use [OAuth 2.0 for login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login). GFC is being [shut down](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/more-spring-cleaning-out-of-season.html).

Comment: instructions on this page:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
 look for 'googles api console' to set up an api key etc

Comment: @topher OAuth 2.0 and OpenId Connect.

Answer (score 16):

You may be interested in [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) which is an all-in-one solution that lets people choose which identity provider they would like to use to log in to your site. Not only are Google and OpenID supported, but many others as well.

RPX takes care of all the details of interfacing with each identity provider, and gives you a common API to work with.

Comment: I've used this and it is very easy to set up with an ASP.Net site.  Plus it free!

Comment: Even tho i marked the other as correct i think i'll go with your solution :) (He just wins it bc originally i wanted to see google specific api)

Comment: As the guy that wrote the other answer, I'll also agree that RPX is probably the best way to actually *implement* OpenID for most usages.  It has a great user interface, and it's easy to install and use.

Comment: If you have more than 2500 users a year you'll have to buy the service.

Comment: PRX does not work for clients which must not use JavaScript.  Instead real OpenID 2.0 works without JavaScript like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app

[Create a Google Developers Console project and client ID.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project)

Load the Google Platform Library

You must include the Google Platform Library on your web pages that integrate Google Sign-In.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Specify your app's client ID

Specify the client ID you created for your app in the Google Developers Console with the google-signin-client_id meta element.

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

Note: You can also specify your app's client ID with the client_id parameter of the gapi.auth2.init() method.

Add a Google Sign-In button

The easiest way to add a Google Sign-In button to your site is to use an automatically rendered sign-in button. With only a few lines of code, you can add a button that automatically configures itself to have the appropriate text, logo, and colors for the sign-in state of the user and the scopes you request.

To create a Google Sign-In button that uses the default settings, add a div element with the class g-signin2 to your sign-in page:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

**Other Info. could be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)**

---

**Other Possible Solution is**

[**Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

*Auth Protocols*

OAuth 2.0 Overview

OpenID Connect

OAuth 2.0 for Server-side Web Apps

OAuth 2.0 for JavaScript Web Apps

OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps

Comment: Is there  a way of doing the basics of google login with direct HTTP requests, i.e. without adding `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` to my page?

Comment: OK, you may have your reasons to do so, what about copying it's content and adding it to your site ?

Comment: also you can have a look at these steps  
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is the [Google Accounts API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/).

Comment: when you click that link look for 'googles api console' to set up a key etc

Answer (score 2):

> but I would like to allow signing in with Google

In this case, add the following code

***HTML***

```
 <div id="mySignin" onclick="login()"><img src="google_image_here.png" alt="google" style="cursor:pointer;height: 60px;width: 309px;"/></div>
```

***JS***

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function login() 
        {
          var myParams = {
            'clientid' : 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
            'callback' : 'loginCallback',
            'approvalprompt':'force',
            'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
          };
          gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
        }

        function loginCallback(result)
        {
            if(result['status']['signed_in'])
            {
                var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get(
                {
                    'userId': 'me'
                });
                request.execute(function (resp)
                {
                    /* console.log(resp);
                    console.log(resp['id']); */
                    var email = '';
                    if(resp['emails'])
                    {
                        for(i = 0; i < resp['emails'].length; i++)
                        {
                            if(resp['emails'][i]['type'] == 'account')
                            {
                                email = resp['emails'][i]['value'];//here is required email id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   var usersname = resp['displayName'];//required name
                });
            }
        }
        function onLoadCallback()
        {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('YOUR_API_KEY');
            gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1',function(){});
        }

            </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              (function() {
               var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
               po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
               var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
             })();
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you tell how to pass state parameter along with request?

Answer (score 2):

**Google SignIn simple steps to integrate:**

1. First go to [this](https://console.developers.google.com/) link(https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Select a project from the dropdown available in the top left. If you are not creating a project yet.Please create a project

[image]

3. After creating a project click the **OAuth consent screen** and fill those details like the Application name and application logo. optional details like domain URL, redirect URL
4. Go to credentials and click create credentials dropdown & click Oauth client id. Fill the details in form 
   [image]
5. Note down the client Id and secret key for signIn API integration
6. For API integration, look at [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#specify_your_apps_client_id). For [react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) and [angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login) applications so many NPM packages are avilable for easy configuration.

Comment: Is a private policy page also essential?

Comment: this comment is outdated unfortunately  and needs update :(

Comment: how can allow all user to connect to the application because i must add the email in google api  console

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think what you want is [Google Friend Connect](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/)</strike>

edit: No you don't any more as it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into openId (http://openid.net/)  which is what SO uses, and is supported by Google.

Comment: Telling somebody to look at openid.net for sign in purpose is like telling somebody who wants something to eat to look at a fishing supply store.  It simply does not help.  Period.